# fullcalendar won't let me resize an event (cursor doesn't show, i'm doing it wrong)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, fullcalendar

Hi stack trace bug chasers, I'm here to ask for help... I'm on symfony2, with twitter bootstrap and I'm desperately trying to enable resizing of my elements sent to the calendar through JSON by doing the following, I can drag the events, but not resize them... :

Screenshot : http://nimga.fr/f/oDrdH.png

into the controller :

```
foreach($events as $event) {

    $start = $event - > getDate();
    $allDay = ($event - > getLength() >= 8);
    $newevent = array('title' = > $event - > getTask() - > getName(),
        'start' = > $start - > format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'id' = > $event - > getId(),
        'allDay' = > $allDay,
        'end' = > $start - > modify('+'.$event - > getLength().
            ' hour') - > format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $eventsArray[] = $newevent;
}
return $this - > render('IntranetTimesheetBundle:Task:displayall.html.twig', array('htmlTree' = > $htmlTree, 'eventlist' = > json_encode($eventsArray)));
```

and in the view :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
    weekends: false, // will hide Saturdays and Sundays
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    slotMinutes: 60,
    minTime: 7,
    maxTime: 19,
    events: {
        {
            eventlist | raw
        }
    },
    editable: true,
    resizable: true,
    eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
        var DATA = {
            "event_title": event.title,
            "event_id": event.id,
            "event_date": event.start,
            "dayDelta": dayDelta,
            "minuteDelta": minuteDelta,
            "allDay": allDay
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "move",
            data: DATA,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //to do in case of success
            }
        });
    },
    eventResizeStart: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
        console.log('RESIZE START ' + event.title);

    },
    eventResizeStop: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
        console.log('RESIZE STOP ' + event.title);

    },
    eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
        console.log('RESIZE!! ' + event.title);
        console.log(dayDelta + ' days'); //this will give the number of days you extended the event
        console.log(minuteDelta + ' minutes');

    }
})
```

I got jQuery and it's UI and droppable extensions loaded and still no arrow cursor to indicate that i can resize the event. Here is my head with the "dependencies"

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.4/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.4/fullcalendar.print.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.4/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: We're **not** bug chasers.

Comment: @ldrumm It was a joke...

Comment: @user2492963 When you initiate JQuery resizable it adds a class (ui-resizable) to the element. Can you confirm that your event element has this class?

Comment: @heymega yeah, ui-resizable is loaded and my element can access it...

Comment: `function x called with arguments: [object Object]
function x called with arguments: .ui-resizable-handle, [object Object]`

Comment: yeah and @ldrumm hope I did not offended you, i was just joking.

Comment: @kuzko Have you checked your browsers dev console? There might be some JS errors being flagged.

Comment: the thing is that there is none... i solved all of them, and the code is clean... but the thing is that the resizing pointer just wont show up... i'm going to show you with screenshots

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I just found where the problem comes from : 
The "fullcalendar.print.css" overrides the basic "fullcalendar.css" and sets the resizing handle in "display: none"
So with wiping the print css, it works.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Add media="print" to your print stylesheet!                        

<link rel="stylesheet" href="your/path/to/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print" />

Comment: yeah, that is what I did afterwards ^^ (i'm still a beginning dev)

Comment: @kuzko .. Am facing the same issue (Can't get resize icon). I have added media = "print" for fullcalendar.print.css . Can you please help me out to debug this. Thanks in advance

Comment: you saved my life - I've been fighting this for about 3hrs - thx!

Answer (score 9):

Finaly i find the solution:
Add allDay to each event!

```
var event = {
    start: startEvent,
    end: endEvent,
    title: "Test",
    allDay: true
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Only Long Event is re sizable. that event not have time along with the date.
Example:

```
events: [
    {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2014-06-01'
    },
    {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2014-06-07',
        end: '2014-06-10'
    },
    {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2014-06-09T16:00:00'
    },
    {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2014-06-16T16:00:00'
    },
    {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2014-06-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2014-06-12T12:30:00'
    },
    {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: '2014-06-12T12:00:00'
    },
    {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: '2014-06-13T07:00:00'
    },
    {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2014-06-28'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add allDay : True to each event or just put allDayDefault={true} in calendar property. It will do the same.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method.

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
  eventResize: this.resizeCalendarEvent.bind(this)
}
function resizeCalendarEvent(event){
  console.log('event:', event)
}
```